# Visual Studio - VscHost gives a Main entry point not defined

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception

I have a main project that works just fine but every time I try to debug a one on one TFS branch we made (exactly the same code), I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=Main entry point not defined.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner..ctor(AppDomain domain, ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

**It works perfectly fine on the PCs of my colleagues and it also works fine when I open it from the debug folder but when I try to debug, it doesn't start as the debugger fails.**

I've tried the following:

- Create a new entry point
- Reinstall visual studio and disable all plugins
- Try with x86/any CPU or debug/release
- Try it in a new TFS path
- Disable the Debug/"Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".

The last option did work, I can now debug. So there seems to be a problem with the **vshost**.

Any idea on how I can fix the hosting process? Formatting and reinstalling everything is only a last-line solution.